# Swap each value to a different value

Tags: r

Below is the swapping function which swap values lesser than 10 in a list

```
swapFun <- function(x, n = 10){
inx <- which(x < n)
x[sample(inx)] <- x[inx]
x
}
```

For example, the original list is 1, 2, 3, 10, 4, 11.

After swapping by sampling , this list may be 2, 1, 4, 10, 3, 11 or 1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 11.

But I want to swap each value lesser than 10 to a different value lesser than 10.

For example, the first outcome (ie 2, 1, 4, 10, 3, 11) is what I want because each value lesser than 10 has been swapped to a different value lesser than 10.

However the second outcome (ie 1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 11.) is not what I want because 1 and 4 have not been swapped to a different value lesser than 10.

If there are no feasible solution, just print 'no feasible solution'

Any suggestions? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the values less than 10. By the theory of derangements, approximately 1/e (37%) of randomly chosen permutations are derangements, so a hit or miss approach is reasonable, with an important caveat.

There might be repetitions among the items less than `n`. Not all permutations of those items are distinguishable, so not all derangements of the items look like derangements: swapping two 2s with each other (for example) is in some sense a derangement, but it wouldn't look like a derangement. The `1/e` heuristic applies to raw permutations of positions, not distinguishable permutations of values. If the number of repetitions is high, it might take longer than 1/e would suggest. If in your use-case the performance isn't satisfactory, you would need to replace `sample()` in the function definitions by a more sophisticated function that picks random distinguishable permutations.

As far as feasibility goes, there will be a feasible solution so long as the most common element less than `n` doesn't account for more than 50% of the items less than `n`

```
derangement <- function(x){
  if(max(table(x)) > length(x)/2) return(NA)
  while(TRUE){
    y <- sample(x)
    if(all(y != x)) return(y)
  }
}

swapFun <- function(x, n = 10){
  inx <- which(x < n)
  y <- derangement(x[inx])
  if(length(y) == 1) return(NA) 
  x[inx] <- y
  x
}
```

For example,

```
> set.seed(10)
> swapFun(c(1,2,10,4,11,2,12))
[1]  2  4 10  2 11  1 12
> swapFun(c(2,2,10,4,11,2,12))
[1] NA
```

Note that no valid derangement has length 1, but `NA` has length 1, so testing the length of `y` is an effective way to test if it is possible to derange the values. The function returns `NA` if no derangement of the values less than n exists. You can test for NA and print "No feasible solutions" if you want

Comment: I have test it with `x <- c(1,2,10,4,11,2,12)`, it returns `NA`. However, it should have  a feasible solution, say 2, 1, 10, 2, 11, 4, 12.

Comment: @Orchard'sStory Good catch! Thanks. I didn't think carefully enough about what would make a solution feasible. The criterion for feasibility is rather simple. See the edited code (which works for your example).

Comment: @Orchard'sStory I fixed another bug. The code should work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I apply it to a matrix and just output the permutations by some certain conditions, say the sum of one specific row stay unchanged? For example, the original matrix is `matrix(c(1,1,0,2,12,13), nrow=2)` . After swapping the values lesser than say 10, for example I want the sum of the second column  is the same with old matrix. Here the 'second' are the input artificial parameters. And all values lesser than 10 should be swapped to another value lesser than 10. If there is no feasible solutIon, return `NA`. Many thanks.

Comment: @Orchard'sStory You could try a hit-and-miss approach with a time-out condition (e.g. no solution in 1000 attempts) as a proxy for determining if there are no feasible solutions. Run `swapFun` in a loop while checking if the additional constraint (or constraints) is satisfied My hunch is that your additional constraint turns feasibility into an NP-complete problem. It really is a fundamentally different question. Perhaps you could post another question rather than adding additional constraints in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This function gives you all the unique permutations for the numbers < m while keeping the positions of numbers >= m the same.

```
require(combinat)

x <- c(1,2,10,4,11,2,12)
m <- 10

swapFun <- function(x, m){

  # determine positions of values to be permutated or fixed
  xi <- which(x < m)
  xj <- which(x >= m)

  # make permuations
  xp <- do.call(rbind, permn(x[xi]))

  # make matrix with permutated and fixed values
  xn <- matrix(nrow = nrow(xp), ncol = length(x))
  xn[ ,xi] <- xp
  xn[ ,xj] <- sort(rep(x[xj],nrow(xp)))

  # delete duplicates
  d <- !duplicated(apply(xn, 1, paste, collapse = "_"))
  xn <- xn[d,]

  return(xn)
}

swapFun(x,m)

> swapFun(x,m)
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    1    2   10    4   11    2   12
 [2,]    1    2   10    2   11    4   12
 [3,]    2    1   10    2   11    4   12
 [4,]    2    1   10    4   11    2   12
 [5,]    1    4   10    2   11    2   12
 [6,]    4    1   10    2   11    2   12
 [7,]    4    2   10    1   11    2   12
 [8,]    2    4   10    1   11    2   12
 [9,]    2    4   10    2   11    1   12
[10,]    4    2   10    2   11    1   12
[11,]    2    2   10    4   11    1   12
[12,]    2    2   10    1   11    4   12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I apply it to a matrix and just output the unique permutations by some certain conditions, say  the sum stay unchanged? for example, the original matrix is `matrix(c(1,1,0,2,12,13), nrow=2) `. 
  After swapping the values lesser than say 10, for example I want the sum of the second column and the sum of the first row of the new matrix respectively are the same with old matrix. Here the 'second' and 'first' are the input artificial parameters.And all values lesser than 10 should be swapped to another value lesser than 10. If there is no feasible solutIon, return ·NA`.

Comment: This is possible but I have no time to code it now :(